# When Return type is a class name of a method

Tags: java, arraylist

So,the question is:

public Contact viewContactGivenPhone(long phoneNumber) -  This method should return the contact details which has the phoneNumber given as parameter.

i created this method :

```
 public Contact viewContactGivenPhone(long phoneNumber){
    for(Contact ob:phoneBook){
        if(ob.getPhoneNumber() == phoneNumber ){
           
            return new Contact(ob.getFirstName(),ob.getLastName(),
                 ob.getPhoneNumber(),ob.getEmailId());
        }
    }
}
```

here phoneBook is an arrayList which stores details(firstname,lastname,phonenumber, emailid).

I am unable to write code for this requirement. help me!!

thanks

Comment: Okay what is the problem that you are facing here ?You can simply return ob from  the method

Comment: What is the type used to create the ArrayList phonebook. It seems ypu might be incorrectly casting its contents to Contact. Also share code for Contact class for better reference.

Comment: You should [edit] your question and post a [mcve] so that people can reproduce your problem and test their solutions. You should post the code for class `Contact`. You should also post the declaration of `phoneBook`.

Comment: when m trying to return ob its showing me compile time error "ob is not found"

Answer (score 1):

Returning ob from the method should help you . You dont need to create a new object and return it.

```
 public Contact viewContactGivenPhone(long phoneNumber){
    for(Contact ob:phoneBook){
        if(ob.getPhoneNumber() == phoneNumber ){
           
            return ob;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WHAT should i return in the last of this method as i have to return an empty object of contact  class but in contact class there is a parameterised constructor.

Comment: You can return null , if there is no match found. Or else only option is create an object and return with empty data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java streams as follows

Also your function is more like a utility and not object specific, I believe it should be static

```java
public static Contact viewContactGivenPhone(long phoneNumber){
        return phonebook.stream().filter(c -> c.getPhonenumber()==phoneNumber).findFirst().get();
    }
```